# Alternatives to flex wrapping

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

Are there other ways to wrap these picture items that have the `display: flex;` property? Right now I am wrapping them using the `flex-wrap` property, but are there any more out there?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

img {}

h1 {}

p {}

a {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/512/" alt="">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <p>Lorizzle ipsizzle dolor shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle amizzle, yo mamma fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle elit. Nullizzle mofo velizzle, dizzle volutpizzle, suscipizzle fo shizzle, phat vizzle, fizzle. Pellentesque eget rizzle. Sizzle
      erizzle. Shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle izzle bling bling dapibus turpis tempizzle crunk.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/" alt="">
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <p>Lorizzle ipsizzle dolor shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle amizzle, yo mamma fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle elit. Nullizzle mofo velizzle, dizzle volutpizzle, suscipizzle fo shizzle, phat vizzle, fizzle. Pellentesque eget rizzle. Sizzle
      erizzle. Shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle izzle bling bling dapibus turpis tempizzle crunk.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/512/" alt="">
    <h1>Title 3</h1>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <p>Lorizzle ipsizzle dolor shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle amizzle, yo mamma fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle elit. Nullizzle mofo velizzle, dizzle volutpizzle, suscipizzle fo shizzle, phat vizzle, fizzle. Pellentesque eget rizzle. Sizzle
      erizzle. Shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle izzle bling bling dapibus turpis tempizzle crunk.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/256/" alt="">
    <h1>Title 4</h1>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <p>Lorizzle ipsizzle dolor shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle amizzle, yo mamma fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle elit. Nullizzle mofo velizzle, dizzle volutpizzle, suscipizzle fo shizzle, phat vizzle, fizzle. Pellentesque eget rizzle. Sizzle
      erizzle. Shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle izzle bling bling dapibus turpis tempizzle crunk.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/" alt="">
    <h1>Title 5</h1>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <p>Lorizzle ipsizzle dolor shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle amizzle, yo mamma fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle elit. Nullizzle mofo velizzle, dizzle volutpizzle, suscipizzle fo shizzle, phat vizzle, fizzle. Pellentesque eget rizzle. Sizzle
      erizzle. Shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle izzle bling bling dapibus turpis tempizzle crunk.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/512/" alt="">
    <h1>Title 6</h1>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <p>Lorizzle ipsizzle dolor shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle amizzle, yo mamma fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle elit. Nullizzle mofo velizzle, dizzle volutpizzle, suscipizzle fo shizzle, phat vizzle, fizzle. Pellentesque eget rizzle. Sizzle
      erizzle. Shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle izzle bling bling dapibus turpis tempizzle crunk.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/" alt="">
    <h1>Title 7</h1>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <p>Lorizzle ipsizzle dolor shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle amizzle, yo mamma fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle elit. Nullizzle mofo velizzle, dizzle volutpizzle, suscipizzle fo shizzle, phat vizzle, fizzle. Pellentesque eget rizzle. Sizzle
      erizzle. Shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle izzle bling bling dapibus turpis tempizzle crunk.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to using `flex-wrap: wrap` would be to switch from `flex-direction: row` to `column` using a media query.

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/x6zqy8kr/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

img {}

h1 {}

p {}

a {
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  /* flex-wrap: wrap; */
}

.item {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

@media ( max-width: 500px ) {
.container {
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/512/" alt="">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <p>Lorizzle ipsizzle dolor shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle amizzle, yo mamma fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle elit. Nullizzle mofo velizzle, dizzle volutpizzle, suscipizzle fo shizzle, phat vizzle, fizzle. Pellentesque eget rizzle. Sizzle
      erizzle. Shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle izzle bling bling dapibus turpis tempizzle crunk.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/" alt="">
    <h1>Title 2</h1>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <p>Lorizzle ipsizzle dolor shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle amizzle, yo mamma fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle elit. Nullizzle mofo velizzle, dizzle volutpizzle, suscipizzle fo shizzle, phat vizzle, fizzle. Pellentesque eget rizzle. Sizzle
      erizzle. Shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle izzle bling bling dapibus turpis tempizzle crunk.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/512/" alt="">
    <h1>Title 3</h1>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <p>Lorizzle ipsizzle dolor shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle amizzle, yo mamma fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle elit. Nullizzle mofo velizzle, dizzle volutpizzle, suscipizzle fo shizzle, phat vizzle, fizzle. Pellentesque eget rizzle. Sizzle
      erizzle. Shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle izzle bling bling dapibus turpis tempizzle crunk.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/256/" alt="">
    <h1>Title 4</h1>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <p>Lorizzle ipsizzle dolor shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle amizzle, yo mamma fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle elit. Nullizzle mofo velizzle, dizzle volutpizzle, suscipizzle fo shizzle, phat vizzle, fizzle. Pellentesque eget rizzle. Sizzle
      erizzle. Shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle izzle bling bling dapibus turpis tempizzle crunk.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/" alt="">
    <h1>Title 5</h1>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <p>Lorizzle ipsizzle dolor shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle amizzle, yo mamma fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle elit. Nullizzle mofo velizzle, dizzle volutpizzle, suscipizzle fo shizzle, phat vizzle, fizzle. Pellentesque eget rizzle. Sizzle
      erizzle. Shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle izzle bling bling dapibus turpis tempizzle crunk.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1024/512/" alt="">
    <h1>Title 6</h1>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <p>Lorizzle ipsizzle dolor shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle amizzle, yo mamma fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle elit. Nullizzle mofo velizzle, dizzle volutpizzle, suscipizzle fo shizzle, phat vizzle, fizzle. Pellentesque eget rizzle. Sizzle
      erizzle. Shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle izzle bling bling dapibus turpis tempizzle crunk.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/512/512/" alt="">
    <h1>Title 7</h1>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <p>Lorizzle ipsizzle dolor shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle amizzle, yo mamma fo shizzle mah nizzle fo rizzle, mah home g-dizzle elit. Nullizzle mofo velizzle, dizzle volutpizzle, suscipizzle fo shizzle, phat vizzle, fizzle. Pellentesque eget rizzle. Sizzle
      erizzle. Shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle izzle bling bling dapibus turpis tempizzle crunk.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

And some day an alternative will be `display: grid`:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

[**Pen demo**](https://codepen.io/ksiabani/pen/wqLRxo)

Comment: you are life Savior bro In ejs template engine in gmail especially display flex works, but flex-direction property does not.Applied your solution and it worked Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An other alternative to flex is to remove `display: flex` on the container and use `display: inline-block` on all item images.

```
.item{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```